# 'export * from @react-navigation/core' error

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

I keep getting `export * from @react-navigation/core.  Unexpected token export` whenever I try to run my test for my project :

https://github.com/MatTaNg/React-Native
(run npm i && npm run test:watch [don't worry npm i doesn't take long its a small project])

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watchAll"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.27",
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.10.1",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^3.3.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.41",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.62.13",
    "jest": "^26.2.2",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native)",
    "node_modules/?!(react-navigation)"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I'm just not able to figure this out.  Something with react-navigation core is messing everything up I think.

Another, separate issue is that for some reason the HTML (jsx) isn't showing up on my mobile device (IOS) but its working fine in the browser.  Seems like its just ignoring all the html inside my route.

EDIT:

I've followed the docs https://docs.expo.io/guides/testing-with-jest/

I've just added this to my package.json:

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
    ]
  },
```

But now I'm getting this error when I run my test:

[image]

Comment: did you check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63552050/8079868

Comment: Yeah, I went through the docs and updated my answer.  I didn't have a ton of time to debug the error and was going to respond when I did but I did a push to my branch if you want to take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using expo therefore, you need to install `expo-jest` and use `"preset": "jest-expo"`

```
yarn add jest-expo --dev
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "test": "jest"
},
"jest": {
  "preset": "jest-expo"
}
```

Here is [**DOCS**](https://docs.expo.io/guides/testing-with-jest/) for Expo jest. so, change expo jest configuration according to docs like below.

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watchAll"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.27",
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.10.1",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^3.3.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.41",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.62.13",
    "jest": "^26.2.2",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5",
    "jest-expo": "^38.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
    ]
  },
  "private": true
}
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Okay so I got past that error but then I got a 'direction' is undefined error.  Some SO answer told me to mock react-native-gesture-handle by adding
   "setupFiles": [
      "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
    ]
to my package.json, which fixed it... but then it caused a 'Native module cannot be null' error. Do you know how to resolve this?